# PHP Creating CSR using existing private key

Tags: php, openssl, private-key, csr

```
<?php 
$c = $_POST['c'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$cn = $_POST['cn'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['pass'];
echo "$c<BR>$city<br>$cn<br>$mail";
$key = $_POST['key'];
$dn = array(
"countryName" => "$c",
"stateOrProvinceName" => ".",
"localityName" => "$city",
"organizationName" => ".",
"organizationalUnitName" => ".",
"commonName" => "$cn",
"emailAddress" => "$key"
//"passphase" => "$p"
);
// Generate a certificate signing request
$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $key);
var_dump($csr);
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
echo $msg . "<br />\n";
?>
```

It is showing me an error:

```
Warning: openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 48 -&gt; -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- M[...]= -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- (failed; check error queue and value of string_mask OpenSSL option if illegal characters are reported) in D:\wamp\www\csr.php on line 21
```

and

```
boolean false
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long
```

This is what I found on php.net

```
mixed openssl_csr_new ( array $dn , resource &$privkey [, array $configargs [, array $extraattribs ]] )
```

`$pivkey` should be a resource type, what if I already have got a private key as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd use [phpseclib, a pure PHP CSR implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey($_POST['key']);

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setPrivateKey($key);
$x509->setDN(array(
    'countryName' => $_POST['c'],
    'stateOrProvinceName' => '.',
    'localityName' => $_POST['city'],
    'organizationName' => '.',
    'organizationalUnitName' => '.',
    'commonName' => $_POST['cn'],
    'emailAddress' => $_POST['email']
));

$csr = $x509->signCSR();

echo $x509->saveCSR($csr);
?>
```