# generate CSR key from private key

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, csr

I need to generate a CSR key from a private key/cert

When doing this I get an error

> openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 48 ->  (failed; check error
>   queue and value of string_mask OpenSSL option if illegal characters
>   are reported) test.php(33)

```
$dn = [
    'commonName'            => '123@-1552-21',// 'func_id@activationcode',
    'organizationalUnitName'=> 'test',
    'organizationName'      => 'test',
    'localityName'          => 'DK',
    'stateOrProvinceName'   => 'DK',
    'countryName'           => 'DK',
    'emailAddress'          => ''
];

$csr = [
    'private_key_bits'  => 2048,
    'private_key_type'  => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    'encrypt_key'       => true
];

$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private('./1_0010444508001.pem');

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $private_key, [
    'digest_alg' => 'sha256'
]);

openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout);
openssl_pkey_export($private_key, $pkeyout, '');

echo $csrout . "\n" . $pkeyout;
```

Comment: I don't want to flag this as a duplicate because [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903300/php-creating-csr-using-existing-private-key) suggests using a different library. Maybe if you can't get this to work, that option may be of use.

Comment: *"...dn:add_entry_by_NID 48 ..."* -  does not look like it complains about the private key but instead about your `dn`. NID 48 is `emailAddress`, thus check this part of dn.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks.. the `emailAddress` can't be empty.. create an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 48 -> (failed; check error queue and value of string_mask OpenSSL option if illegal characters are reported) test.php(33)

The problem is not the private key but the problem is in the `dn`. It complains that there is a problem adding the attribute with NID 48 to the CSR. NID 48 [is the NID for emailAddress](http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/asn1-obj-names.html) so it complains about the contents of this field. Looks like it should not be empty.

Comment: The list of mandatory fields will depend on the `openssl.cnf` content in force for the CSR generation, typically the `req_distinguished_name` that lists what must be in the certificate, and hence in the certificate request. It typically depends on the CA to which the CSR will be handled to.